# Copy Table from Database from Dropbox to App

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I had written following code to copy database file from dropbox account to app database.But i want to copy only specific table from Dropbox to App database table.Is it possible.

```
 protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final File tempDir = context.getCacheDir();
        File tempFile;
        FileWriter fr;
        try {
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            String currentDBPath = "//data//"+ "loginscreen.example.com.girviapp" +"//databases//"+DATABASE_NAME;
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(currentDB);

            Entry existingentry= dropbox.metadata( path ,1000,null,true,null);


            if (existingentry.contents.size() != 0)
            {
                for (Entry ent :existingentry.contents)
                {
                    String name = ent.fileName();
                    if(name.equals(DATABASE_NAME))
                    {    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(currentDB);
                        DropboxFileInfo info = dropbox.getFile(path + DATABASE_NAME, null, outputStream, null);

                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer here depends on exactly what you're looking to do.

If you want to be able to download only a specific table from the database file stored on Dropbox, in order to save bandwidth by not downloading all of the data, then no, this isn't possible. The unit of storage in the Dropbox API you're using is the file, and Dropbox doesn't know what the individual tables in your database file are, so it doesn't have a way for you to specify a particular table.

On the other hand, if you don't mind downloading the entire file from Dropbox, then yes, this is possible. Just download the file as you're doing, and then load it up as a database locally. Then query out just the data you want, that is, the desired table, and do what you need with it.